# diff3-like program for windows?

Tags: windows, diff, meld, kdiff3, diff3

I'm a linux user, and normally I use kdiff3 to compare 3 (text) files between each others (for example, when there are svn conflics).
I know of various programs to do that (like diff3 or meld) but none for windows.

Is there a 3-file-differ for windows available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a version of [kdiff3 for windows](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: wow, I'm really blind! I passed over the sf link just before asking here

Comment: Happens to the best of us.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also get [meld working on Windows](https://live.gnome.org/Meld/Windows).